# Using Python to automate data cleanup, some issues

Tags: python, code-cleanup

I have to process ~16,000 rows of data. Each row is a transaction record, with several parts. For example:
    row= [ID, thing, widget]

What I would like to do is kind of simple- for each row, compare it to the rest of the rows one by one. If row A has a unique ID and unique widget, I want to write it to an outfile. Otherwise, I don't need it. (This program basically automates data cleanup for me.) Here's what I have so far:

```
try:
    infile=open(file1, 'r')
    for line in infile:
        line_wk=line.split(",")
        outfile=open(file2, 'r')
        for line in outfile:
            line_wk2=line.split(",")
            if line_wk[0]==line_wk2[0]:
                if line_wk[2]!=line_wk2[2]: #ID is not unique, but the widget is
                    to_write=','.join(line_wk) #queued to write later
            else:
                to_write=','.join(line_wk) #queued to write later
    if len(to_write)>0:
        outfile.close()
        outfile=open(file2, 'a')
        outfile.write(to_write)
        outfile.close()
        outfile=open(file2, 'r')
        infile.close()
        outfile.close()

except:
    print("Something went wrong.")
```

Running this on a small test set, it stays within the 'try' block but otherwise just writes everything, not only the ones with a unique ID and widget. I assume there is an infinitely simpler way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please give an example row? And the data type of each column? If under Linux, shell command like awk might work better.

Comment: **never** use a plain `except:` this way. You throw away valuable traceback information if your program crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create a dictionary where the key is a tuple of `(ID, widget)` and the value is `thing`.  Dictionary keys are guaranteed unique.  So, your code would look something like this.

```
uniques = {}
with open("yourfile.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ID, thing, widget = line.strip().split(',')
        uniques[(ID, widget)] = thing

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for k, v in uniques.iteritems():
        outfile.write("%s,%s,%s\n" % (k[0], v, k[1]))
```

If preserving their original order is important then you can use `OrderedDict` from the [collections](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) package

You can also clean up how the `outfile.write` line is written, but it should work as is.

Lastly, since it appears you are reading/writing csv (comma separated values) format, you can make use of the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

---

To test this I wrote a script

```
import random
import string

IDS = range(1, 100)
widgets = ['ITEM_%s' % (i, ) for i in range(10)]
thing_chars = list(string.uppercase + string.lowercase)

def get_thing():
    return "".join(random.sample(thing_chars, 10))

with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as out:
    for i in xrange(0, 16000):
        ID = random.choice(IDS)
        widget = random.choice(widgets)
        thing = get_thing()
        out.write("%s,%s,%s\n" % (ID, thing, widget))
```

It appears to run with the correct results.

Comment: That works perfectly! The version I'm using uses .items instead of .iteritems, but I never would have thought of using a dictionary for the purpose of unique values. Built in class features, where would we be without you...